# sql get the all round count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am having a table with Rounds And Previous rounds

if i give round =13

--LOGIC--

13 previous is 7   =>Count 1

7 previous is  5   =>Count 2

5 previous is  1   =>Count  3

i shoud get count as 3 in sql server

```
============================

| Round  | Previous round  |

============================

|  1     | Null            |
|  2     | Null            |
|  3     | 2               |
|  4     | Null            |   
|  5     |    1            |
|  6     |    4            |   
|  7     |    5            |    
|  13    |    7            |

============================
```

Comment: did you check the answer @ramapriyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you the correct output. Now test it, this one took a hell out of me but worth it. I have added some additional ones like 26 for testing purposes.

```
DECLARE @round int=13

DECLARE @table table(currentround int,previousround int)
insert into @table values
(1,NULL),
(2,NULL),
(3,2),
(4,NULL),
(5,1),
(7,5),
(13,7),
(20,13),
(26,3),
(17,8),
(25,20)


DECLARE @Id int
declare @count int=0
select @Id = @round

while(select count(*)
      from @table c
      where c.currentround <= @Id) > 0

      Begin


select @count =( select @count+1-count(*) From @table curr
left join @table prev
on curr.previousround=prev.currentround
where curr.currentround=@Id and curr.previousround  is null)

select @Id = (Select  prev.currentround 
From @table curr
left join @table prev
on curr.previousround=prev.currentround
where curr.currentround=@Id )

END
select(@count)
```

Comment: That addition 2 is needed for your desired outcome of the question why you suggested it's not needed @ramapriyan c

Comment: Stil not proper

Comment: if u check if i give 13 output =>3

Comment: if i give 3 out put =>1

Comment: can you check this now,Only thing is you need to put a value that is in the table, test it and let me know, i spent a lot of time on this